# Keep text on left and middle of the div, not center

Tags: css

I want to be able to keep a text on the left, but in the  middle of a div.

```
<div id=sel>text goes here</div>
```

and my CSS for the same

```
sel{
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The characters and lines of the text may vary.  I am more focussed on the text with a single line that sits on the top.  I do not want to use position:absolute/relative.

Appreciate all help.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, a side note: `vertical-align` only works with table cells. As a result, this problem is trivial with table cells. See [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html).

Otherwise you will need to put that content inside another block and then vertically center that block within the outer block. See [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html).

Comment: Tried: top: -50%, display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; separately, but not working

Comment: @Jean the linked trick works. You must be missing something. Do you have the *three* divs? Do you have a `DOCTYPE`?

Comment: This is how my code is
<div><span>text goes here to middle and left</span></div>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @Jean read the example from the second link carefully. There are (and need to be) **three** divs. Secondly, without starting a second topic I'll summarize: don't use XHTML. There's no need. It adds no value. It just creates problems.

Comment: cletus now you have confused me totally

Comment: @Jean that `DOCTYPE` is XHTML. I can only assume your markup is XHTML. If so, go back to HTML 4.01 `DOCTYPE` and markup. XHTML just causes problems. If not that, what are you confused by?

Comment: To start off, we are moving our office....next...I am about 20ms off from my desk...next...why do I require 3 divs?

sorry I am all fuzzed up in my head..

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with a single line only, the easiest way is probably to set the line-height equal to the height of the div, for example:

```
#sel {
    text-align: left;
    height: 4em;
    line-height: 4em;
}
```

For other scenarios, have a look at [this page](http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/)

Comment: That would get all text out of place, if the div contains more than one line

Comment: That's why I wrote "if you are dealing with a single line only". I must have misunderstood your sentence "I am more focussed on the text with a single line that sits on the top." I do not know what exactly you mean by this.